# How to reflect the changes in Order Confirmation Files from Bigcommerce Checkout-JS?

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I tried to change the files for the checkout page using checkout-js. It is working. However, when I changed some files for the order confirmation page, it does not reflect.
May I know how to use the order confirmation files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is only not working locally?
Have you pushed up changes to the store?